# Finding the lat-long of the corners in a Google Maps window

Tags: google-maps, mapping, maps

Using the Google Maps API, how can I get the latitude and longitude of the corners of the map display area?

That is, if my map is 300px wide and 400px tall, how can I find the lat-long of the points at (0,0) and (300,400)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [getBounds()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). From the doc:

> Returns the the visible rectangular region of the map view in geographical coordinates.

That function returns exactly what you want:  the southwest and northeast corners of your map. The first pair of coordinates are the lower left (southwest) coordinates and the second pair is the upper right (northeast) coordinates.

Comment: (0,0) is likely intended to be the northwest corner, in which case Matt will need the latitude of the second coordinate, but the longitude from the first.

Comment: Good point, but I figured since we're talking about a map and not a generic screen, the origin would be the lower left, not the upper left. Either way, getBounds() will return the info Matt wants. It's just a matter of parsing it...

Comment: map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng() = the west bound.   map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat() = the north bound, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Android(Kotlin) you can try this,

```
val curentScreen: LatLngBounds =  mapview.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds

var northeast=curentScreen.northeast
var southwest=curentScreen.southwest
var center=curentScreen.center
Log.v("northeast LatLng","-:"+northeast)
Log.v("southwest LatLng","-:"+southwest)
Log.v("center LatLng","-:"+center)
```