# Matching long & lat within radius

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, mapping, latitude-longitude

I'm thinking of using my map coordinates to allow for location based searching and I don't know where to start.

I have a database of coordidinates - When I enter a suburb, I want to display all matches within a given radius. (i.e. search database of long/lat coords and return all coords that are in an x radius of long/lat of suburb searched)

I'm not sure how to achieve this or where to start?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083472/finding-the-lat-long-of-the-corners-in-a-google-maps-window

Comment: @Argiropoulos Stavros - Using MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Well it really depends on what database you are using. 
the general technique is to use a scaler value function that uses a formula such as:

```
distance = ACOS(SIN(lat1)*SIN(lat2)+COS(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon2-lon1))*6371
```

then you can write a query like:

```
select * 
from locations 
where mydistancefunction(lat1,lng1,locations.lat,locations.lng) < @radius
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of [mysql spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)?Try to create a spatial column in your table i.e. Point and then use the functions that spatial extensions offer so you don't reinvent the wheel