# How to get Bounding Box coordinates for my google map window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project that includes google maps api v3 and PostGres.

What I want to do is to pass the bounding box coordinates(bottom left and top right) of my map window to POSTGRES and get the POI locations for the generated map window on a particular zoom level.

How can I achieve this.. ? Any Ideas? Is there already a direct function for this in api v3?

I've got this on SO but this does not seem to work for me

[Finding the lat-long of the corners in a Google Maps window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083472/finding-the-lat-long-of-the-corners-in-a-google-maps-window)

Comment: What's wrong with 'map.getBounds()'?

Comment: It was my fault.. My implementation was incorrect..!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083472/finding-the-lat-long-of-the-corners-in-a-google-maps-window) is using the Google Maps API v2, use the Google Maps API v3 equivalent [google.maps.Map.getBounds()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

The bounds will not be available until the bounds_changed event has fired, so wrap it in a listener for bounds_changed

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function() {
   // send the new bounds back to your server
   alert("map bounds{"+map.getBounds());
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j46vycqs/)

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function() {
    // send the new bounds back to your server
    document.getElementById("bounds").innerHTML ="map bounds=" + map.getBounds();
  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 90%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="bounds"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```